# ASP.Net Core: How to create a connection string on Macbook pro

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, database-connection, visual-studio-code

I created a project using the asp.net core. I installed visual studio code in my MacBook Pro, I also have MySql.

My question is how to connect that project to MySql using visual studio code on mac environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find an appsettings.json file that stores the app's environment variables. In there, you can set your database connection string as a variable:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

Then, in your project's Startup.cs file, you will find a method called 'ConfigureServices'. This is where you set up dependency injection, which would include your database context. In the following example, we are specifying which connection string to use by accessing the 'BloggingDatabase' environment variable and passing that as an option when adding the database context to the project's services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

I would recommend you read the section of the following Microsoft help article that contains more information on connection strings in Asp.Net Core projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the new version (8.0.0) of `MySql.Data` needs this connection String architecture.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=database1;user id=root;SslMode=none;"
  }
```